# RabbitMQ cluster with three nodes

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to do clustering with RabbitMQ. I have added two nodes, but I am unable to add a third one. I have clustered `rabbit@node1` and `rabbit@node2`. Now I am trying to cluster `rabbit@node3` with `rabbit@node1`.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1
Clustering node rabbit@node3 with rabbit@node1 ...
Error: mnesia_not_running
```

Is there any way to add a third node to the cluster? Or any solution for the `Error: mnesia_not_running` error?

Comment: Is MNesia running on node1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When joining a cluster, the target node application should be started, while the source (current) node application should be stopped. An application can be stopped and started with `rabbitmqctl stop_app` and `rabbitmqctl start_app`.

Maybe you have stopped the application on `rabbit@node1`, while joining it to the cluster. In that case you should run `rabbitmqctl start_app` on `rabbit@node1`, or `rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@node1 start_app` to be able to join its cluster. Or you can join the `rabbit@node2` cluster and start the app later.

To have a working cluster you should start the application on all nodes after joining.

Comment: Thats really helpful. But I also sorted it our earlier. The problem was On **Node3** I was performing three steps .....first `stop app` , `reset app` and then I was trying to join. Where as I shouldn't reset app/ I only need to **stop** , **join** and **start**. And all set :)

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when the target node's app is stopped. When joining a node to a RabbitMQ cluster, only the source node (the node which you are trying to link) should be stopped.

On the master node:

```
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

On the current node:

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1
```